# VBA merge cells and **Bold** text of second cell

Tags: vba, excel, substring, text-formatting

I am coding a VBA function to merge two cells and then highlight the text of cell 2 with **bold** formatting

The merging goes well
The call to Sub goes well
But the text format is not applied

I believe it might be caused by the sub executing before the cell is populated with the string - but that's pure guessing - this is my first VBA script

```
Function boldIt(navn As String, ekstra As String)

Dim ln1 As Integer
Dim ln2 As Integer
Dim st1 As String

ln1 = Len(navn)
ln2 = Len(navn) + Len(ekstra)

If (ln1 = ln2) Then
    boldIt = navn
Else
    boldIt = navn & " - " & ekstra
    boldTxt ln1, ln2
End If

End Function

Public Sub boldTxt(startPos As Integer, charCount As Integer)
    With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=startPos, Length:=charCount).Font
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That cannot work.  Selective formatting can only work an actual text string stored within a cell.  Before the function finishes, there is no text string within the cell.  After it finishes, there is a formula in the cell (which returns a text string), **NOT** a plain text string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Sub loops through the columns, takes the strings of the two cells, combines the strings and add them to the target cell, while bolding the text of the second cell

Thanks to @Jeeped for the pointers!

```
Sub boldIt()
Dim pos_bold As Integer
Dim celltxt As String

For i = 2 To 200000
    ' first cell will always be populated - if not - exit
    If (Range("Plan!E" & i).Value = "") Then Exit For

    ' if second cell is empty - take only first cell as normal txt
    If (Range("Plan!F" & i).Value = "") Then
        Range("Kalender!F" & i).Value = Range("Plan!E" & i).Value
    Else
        ' calculate start of bold text
        pos_bold = Len(Range("Plan!E" & i).Value) + 1

        ' create the string
        celltxt = Range("Plan!E" & i).Value & " - " & Range("Plan!F" & i).Value
        ' add string to field and add bold to last part
        With Worksheets("Kalender").Range("F" & i)
            .Value = celltxt
            .Characters(pos_bold).Font.Bold = True
        End With
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I would just run two subs; the function is not returning anything.

```
Option Explicit

Sub boldIt()
    Dim secondOne As String
    With Selection
        secondOne = .Cells(2).Value2
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Merge
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        .Cells(1) = .Cells(1).Value2 & secondOne
        boldTxt .Cells(1), Len(.Cells(1).Value2) - Len(secondOne) + 1, Len(secondOne)
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub boldTxt(rng As Range, startPos As Integer, charCount As Integer)
    With rng.Characters(Start:=startPos, Length:=charCount).Font
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The function works fine and the field is populated as it should be - only it does not bold the text (tried multible versions without the Sub).

Comment: I don't believe you understand *function is not returning anything*. Functions are supposed to return a value; there is no point in using a function in place of a sub if it simply performs actions without returning anything. With that in mid, I used two subs.

Comment: What you do works :-) However, I would like to keep the original cells and add the data to a new cell - looping through the entire column